# How can I find or build a passive RFID tag with a range of 6ft, as well as an associated reader?

Tags: sensor, rfid, passive-components

I am looking to implement a RFID system that uses trilateration to localize a RFID tag.

I have no experience with RFID, and although I have done some basic research, I have no idea where to begin. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You're unlikely to get a good distance reading from passive RFID tags required for trilateration. Passive tags get their transmit energy from the reader. To get a distance in wireless systems you typically look at how much power you receive from a known transmitter, in this case you have to guess at how much power the tag got and then reflected back and account for all those losses. Reading passive tags at six feet is also very difficult.

The first paper I published in college was describing a system I designed using passive RFID tags for aiding localization. I used them to update a kalman filtered dead reckoning system, resetting the system's location to within the four inch read range of passive tags. It was rather novel at the time, got me a full ride for grad school at least.

That being said, you'd probably be better off using active tags if they don't need to last years.

Look at the existing literature for such systems, there are a lot of publications on the topic. They will often share details of the implementation that commercial systems hide. Once you have started your design, come back and ask more specific questions regarding implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Can active tags be used in a small and flexible enclosure? Like a bandage, for example.

Comment: @ZackB For the most part, yes, they can.

Comment: There's an intermediate solution in there too - passive receive, active transmit. Good for battery life. I haven't seen any active tags that are really small (I'd like to know if there are). UHF passive tags have the cheapest tag (10c to 20c) and the largest range. I would assert that a range of 2m+ is feasible with UHF but requires one heck of an output power. Multiple watts. I'm tasked with looking at it myself.

Comment: Two interesting links for background reading: http://www.openbeacon.org/ (6 year battery life, open design). New location technology chips: http://www.decawave.com/products/dwm1000-module. The latter is somewhat beyond my experience level though.

Comment: @carveone Those are good resources. The first is BLE (bluetooth low energy) and the second is UWB (ultra-wide band). Both are excellent methods for indoor localization.