# Ideas for triangulation of a small object within 6 feet

Tags: sensor, system, tag

I'm looking to build a system that can detect the location of a tag within a 6 foot range to an accuracy of one or two inches. I have briefly looked into RFID sensors but I haven't found any that satisfy my needs. Does anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: Do you and ZackB have the same assignment by any chance? You might want to look at the answers to his question instead of adding a duplicate. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/148872/how-can-i-find-or-build-a-passive-rfid-tag-with-a-range-of-6ft-as-well-as-an-as

Comment: Strange that this question got two upvotes in as many minutes when ZachB got zero in half an hour.

Comment: @Samuel Probably because ZachB proposed a solution that not as many people are familiar with, rather than an open ended problem.

Comment: Yes, we have the same project but my question is slightly different. He was asking specifically about RFID while I was asking about general methods for object detection to see if there were any other commonly used methods. I am still looking for any other possible object detection methods other than RFID.

Comment: @Samuel (Apparently) real name and profile photo help establish credibility even with no rep.

Comment: @MeghanO'Lone Do you specifically want triangulation as the question states? Or, as ZachB asked, is triatilation an ok solution?

Comment: Some video cameras and an led inside a ping pong ball, (diffusor)?  Our PS3 has something like that.  maybe a few leds, pointing which way.

Comment: Decawave has what you are looking for. I am trying to do something similar, but the decawave tag is a little bigger than I am looking for.